# Google scripts onOpen adding wrong amount to cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing google script for a P.O. form we have. The first part of the script is an onOpen function that compares two values. if the values are the same it adds 1 to the value of a cell in sheets. If the values are different it sets the value of that cell back to 001. When I run this script by hitting the play button it works fine but when I actually use it by opening the document it adds two to the cell instead of one. When the comparative cells are different is acts as expected and changes the value to 001. I am not sure what is going on. Below is a snippet of the code

```
function onOpen(e) {

var dt = new Date(); // todays date
var mnth = dt.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }); //current month in written out
var yr= dt.getFullYear(); // year in four number format

  //creates day in 2 number format
 if (dt.getDate()<=9) {
   var dy ="0"+dt.getDate();
 }
  else {
    var dy = dt.getDate()
  } 
  //creates month in two number format
 if (dt.getMonth()<=9) {
   var realMnth = dt.getMonth()+1
   var NumMnth="0"+realMnth
 }
  else {
    var NumMnth = dt.getMonth+1
  } 
   //checking to see if what PO for the day this is
  var dateCount = NumMnth+dy+yr
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G1').setValue(dateCount)

  var oldDt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D1').getValue()
  var newDt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G1').getValue()

  if (oldDt == newDt){ 
    var PO = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').getValue()+1
  }
    else {
    var PO = 001

    }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').setValue(PO)
```

Comment: Show view> executions onOpen. Learn to debug and log  variables. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Hello jzannoni, just like @TheMaster has mentioned, would you mind checking the `Stackdriver Logs`? Moreover, is the `onOpen` trigger a simple or installable one? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the executions view. This is my first time using google scripts and writing in any form of java at all. Going to that view helped me solve the issue. I have a simple trigger but back when I was still trying to figure out how to get it to execute I had created an installable one for onopen and an old onedit one. The on open one was executing along with the simple trigger. Deleting the installable one solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see what exactly is the issue with your triggers, you should be checking the  `Stackdriver Logs` so you can check the executions that have taken place.

This is also helpful since you can check which kind of triggers you have and which ones have been triggered.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging).